# Is there a way to apply rig's transformatio after rescaling it without destroying existing animation?

Tags: animation, rigging

Regarding the title of this post. I only noticed my character scale is wrong after creating some animation. I use my root bone(all the other bone are parent to it) to scale up the character in object mode. However, after applying the  scale, all of the animation are completely unusable.

I need to apply it as I need to export it to another engine, which if possible all the scale should be 1.0. So I was wondering is there a way to scale up the rig & model, while also applying the transformation without breaking the animation?